# White liness in character texture

Tags: texturing

Hi I have been getting thin but visable white lines on my character texture in the game engine (Unity). They are appearing where I have had mesh seams, although they are removed on export.

I used stencil painting for the texture and have tried reducing the image seam margin to 1 from 8 before rendering the texture as PNG.

The lines are on the buttock and down the lower legs as circled in yellow.

Can anyone tell me how I could remove these lines?

[image: Character with white Lines]

---

Thanks Blunder. Yet again my problem was not really with Blender, but Unity. I forgot to match the image texture resolution (4096x4096) with the one in Unity which defaults to 2K. Now you have to be an ant to see any white pixels, so it's not even necessary to fiddle with the seam settings in Blender.

However for clarification, would I need to make a new UV map in Blender.[image: Data Panel UV Maps]

And would I need to use the original mesh seams, import the image file and then increase the seam margins. Or would I need to paint the texture anew?

Comment: The margin 1 is not probably enough ...

Comment: The purpose of the margin is to prevent color bleeding when the model is scaled, depending on the distance to the camera. If the margin is too small, neighboring pixels that do not belong to the actual UV island are also projected onto the 3D model and you will see such seam artifacts. You can create a new UV map with a wider margin and then bake the textures to new images.